# Jupyter notebook shows: Javascript error adding output! ReferenceError: google is not defined. See your browser Javascript console for more details

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running Jupyter notebook on AWS platform.
Whenever I run any code (for example `import numpy as np`), this message pops out in the result:

Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: google is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.

Although this message doesn't affect the following running, I would like to know how to fix it.
Thanks in advance

[an example code and message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPJso.png)

Thanks [durga-sury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458691/durga-sury). I'm using SageMaker notebook instances.

Comment: Can you clarify by Jupyter notebook on AWS platform? Are you self-hosting on EC2 or using SageMaker notebook instances/SageMaker Studio?

Comment: I'm using SageMaker notebook instances. Thanks for asking for clarification.

Comment: Curious - is this browser specific? What happens if you stop and start the notebook instance, do you still see the error?

Comment: I restarted the notebook instance and it's fixed. Thank you @durga_sury.